# Change calendar start date from current day?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, filter, calendar

Hello I work in the project and we filter date in the calendar until 10 year past 
when open the calender start from 10 year

I want to make the calendar start from the current day when opening it

```
let group: [UIButton] = [filterOne, filterThree, filterTwo]
group.forEach { item in
    item.backgroundColor = .primaryButtonColor
    item.layer.cornerRadius = 15
}
dateRangePickerViewController.delegate = self
dateRangePickerViewController.minimumDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .year, value: -10, to: Date())

dateRangePickerViewController.maximumDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .year, value: 1, to: Date())
// dateRangePickerViewController.selectedStartCell = Calendar
dateRangePickerViewController.selectedStartDate = Date()
dateRangePickerViewController.selectedEndDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: Date())
self.startDate = Date()
self.endDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: Date())
fromValue.text = self.startDate?.toString(format: "yyyy/MM/dd")
fromValue.text = self.endDate?.toString(format: "yyyy/MM/dd")
```

[image: calender]

Comment: I think there must be some func scrollToDate(_ date: Date) or smth

Comment: What calendar (ui component)  is this?

Comment: inside collection view